# 74AHCT244 did not output the required signal. What could be the problem?

Tags: digital-logic

[image: 74AHCT connections in Altium]
[image: Partial PCB layout in Altium]
[image: Partial schematic in Altium]

I am using an STM32 to control my [TLC5940](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf), which uses different voltage levels. The circuit layout is in schematic shown above.

I wrote a small program to toggle my `Blank` pin. At the controller side (`BLANK_3V3`) I measure a toggle signal from LOW to HIGH. But at the TLC5940 side (`BLANK_4V0`) my signal is always LOW. What can be the cause?

I have changed the supply voltage of the [74AHCT244](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AHC_AHCT244.pdf) to 5V as according to the datasheet, but no change has occurred. I would be really thankful to hear from you.

Comment: What do these red crosses in front of 1A3, 2A0 and 2A1 mean? Could it be the signal is **not** connected? And therefore, there is neither a connection on the PCB? Check the voltage on the 2A0 pin of the 74AHCT244 itself when you toggle it.

Comment: Cause: a short on the output pin maybe?

Comment: I use the cross to avoid error from my software (Altium).  These because the signal on my µC is defined as output in Altium but on the 74AHCT244, I defined it as Input and this will cause an error by compiling if I did not use the red cross. They are actually connection according to my layout and the board that I have. measuring the signal at the resistor level and at pin 2A0 of 74AHCT244, I am getting the toggling signal.

Comment: Did you take ESD precautions when soldering the 74AHCT244?

Comment: I did not solder. It was soldered by a soldering company.

Comment: Check the layout: pin ordering and part orientation. Do you have a clear image of the part on the board?

Comment: I have check and double check the pin ordering and part orientation, but I did not see any error. May I have to make rest and come back and check it again:). But if you see any error on the PCB let me know.

Comment: I guess I have seen the error. I completely mirror the IC and that is why it is not working.

Comment: Yes, you've mirrored the pinout.The soldering company should have reported to you that your pin 1 indicator does not conform to pin 1 on the package.

Comment: @Rompel - Now that you have found the problem, please can you write this as an *answer* (in the "Your Answer" box below) and then accept that answer ("green tick") so that the site knows the problem is effectively closed? The site doesn't know that you have solved your problem by writing that comment above! Thanks.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeat: Thanks for your. but I have to ask if the soldering company must have reported? What could be solution in such a case as I am the only designer and have to review everything myself?